# ImportError: Ubuntu 16.04.3 - Installing basemap module on python 2.7.12

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, python

I am trying to import the `basemap` python module but I get the following error:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

.....

> ImportError: No module named mpltoolkits.basemap

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.3 and python 2.7.12

I checked a lot online and it seems it is a very common problem but I could not find a solution.

Any help?
thanks

update: I followed carefully these instructions https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/ but at the end the basemap module is still not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours spent online I solved the issue by installing anaconda https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html

then `conda install -c anaconda basemap`

and I can eventually import `basemap` from `mpl_toolkits`